# Create new Array of parameter type

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to create a function to parse out all values in a multidimensional `Array` with all but one dimension given. The details are not relevant, but for this function I need to return an one-dimensional `Array` containing values of the same type the original multidimensional `Array` has.

To pass any `Array` with any dimension to my function, I declared the type of this parameter as `Array`. However, how would I create a new `Array` of that specific type (e.g. `Integer`)?

Currently I have the following code:

```
Function GetRow(ByVal arr As Array) As Array
    Dim result As (...) 'This should be Integer() if arr contains Integers, etc.
    Return result
End Function
```

How do I declare the type of `result` to make it having the same type of values as `arr`? `New Array` is not possible as it is declared `MustInherit`.

Comment: Can't give a good answer in VB.Net but this may help:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use generics here so the function can handle any type:

```
Function GetRow(Of T)(ByVal arr() As T) As T()
    Dim result() As T
    ReDim result(arr.Length - 1)
    Array.Copy(arr, result, arr.Length)
    Return result
End Function
```

Sample usage:

```
    Dim iarr() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4}
    Dim copy = GetRow(iarr)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, this does not seem to be able to accept multidimensional Arrays. I guess this is because you declare the type of arr as arr(), i.e. a one-dimensional Array. Could you possibly explain what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, you'll need another overload for multi-dimensional arrays.  Declare the arrays as (,) for 2dim and tweak the code accordingly.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It's not fully generic, but I will only work with one, two or three-dimensional arrays anyway.